# String exception due to array index

Tags: java, html, parsing, jsoup

I have a loop that initiates an array of strings then cuts them to give the desired information:

```
for (Element referenceId: referenceIds){
    ref[i] = referenceId.attr("href");
    String[] str = new String[24]; 
    str[i] = ref[i].substring(ref[i].lastIndexOf("listing-") + 8, ref[i].indexOf(".htm"));
    System.out.println(str[i]); 
    i++;
}
```

However I'm getting an error crashing the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24
    at Jobs.main(Jobs.java:30)
```

What is this and how do I fix it? I've tried changing the array size to less but that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
String[] str = new String[24];
```

to this

```
String[] str = new String[ref.length];
```

Your `ref` array is probably having `25` or more items. So, as soon as the loop iterates over the 25th element (i.e. with index `24`) you get an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 24`.

Comment: It would help if you post the whole method code that covers the `ref` array.

Answer (score 1):

You are iterating over `referenceIds` so you should use the size of this array/list for maybe it will change:

```
String[] str = new String[referenceIds.lenght];
```

You might also want to declare the `String[] str` outside the for loop.

Chears!